# Spring event listener

Tags: spring-boot, java-11

I am publishing an event using spring ApplicationEventPublisher

Method for publishing and publisher

```
 @Autowired
private ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher; 

 private void publishContributorUpdate(long contributorId, boolean isOwner){
    var upe = new DeactivateContributorEvent(this);
    upe.setContributorId(contributorId);
    upe.setOwner(isOwner);

    eventPublisher.publishEvent(upe);
}
```

Event class:

```
public class DeactivateContributorEvent extends ApplicationEvent
```

Listener is here

```
  @Component
  public class ContributorDeactivateEventListener  {

@Autowired
private ContributorDao contributorDao;

@EventListener
public void onContributorDeactivation(final DeactivateContributorEvent event) {


        contributorDao.updateContributor(event.getContributorId(),event.isOwner(),false);
}
}
```

So, the event is published as I have seen but not read. What can be the reason for it? I am using spring-boot 2.1.3

Comment: Everything I see looks OK.  Can you tell us more about how `eventPublisher` is created?  I would also make sure that your `ContributorDeactivateEventListener` class is actually being scanned and instantiated.  You could add a constructor to it and put a breakpoint in that constructor, or add a logging call or "printf", to know that it is being seen by Spring.  (BTW, I'm assuming that when you say "not read", you mean that `onContributorDeactivation` is never being called.)

Comment: @steve that's correct.  onContributorDeactivation method is not called

Comment: Then do you understand what I'm suggesting?  I'd want to know if your `ContributorDeactivateEventListener` object is being created.  My guess is that it is not, because if it were, then Spring should be calling it. - maybe that file/class isn't being scanned by Spring at startup.  That's the best explanation I can think of.

Comment: The only other explanation, it would seem, would be that `eventPublisher` is somehow not acting right.  But since you're not getting a NPE exception when it is called, it must be there, and I can't think how it would be set up to not call your `ContributorDeactivateEventListener` class.  You'd have had to have done something strange in setting it up for it to not be working.  That mechanism is pretty darn simple in Spring. - So my guess is that Spring didn't scan your `ContributorDeactivateEventListener` class for annotations.

Comment: One other thing.  I assume you've looked in your logs for errors regarding all this.  That would be a great thing to do if you haven't, in case there's an answer in the logs.

Comment: Was there ever a resolution here?